# In which case is it advisable to use ActiveResource? and in which case is it not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, ruby-on-rails-3, activeresource

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I am considering to use [ActiveResource](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html) in order to trasmit information from a RoR service application to a RoR client application.

**In general, in which case is it advisable to use ActiveResource? and in which case is it not?**

---

I have many doubts about the use of ActiveResources. The following is just one.

- I have resources consisting of private information and public information. I should not send over *HTTP* private info and so I could not send those with the public info unless I don't hack RoR behaviours. If I use *HTTPS*, so that I don't have to hack the RoR behaviours, *is not too heavy the work for the server?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a dedicated IP OR to buy a subject alternative name certificate so you can do SSL with multiple name-based virtual hosts. It is a little tricky to set up the certificate and then get it used with multiple vhosts, but once you have done it a couple of times, it isn't bad.

http://lanestechblog.blogspot.com/2009/04/creating-ssl-certificates-with-multiple.html

http://backreference.org/2009/12/17/name-based-ssl-virtual-hosts-in-apache/

Answer (score 1):

Your question is more about choosing the right authentication strategy if you are sending across private data. And no, SSL will not put too much extra load on the server. You will need a dedicated IP though.

If you would expand on the list of doubts some more maybe there could be a clearer answer.